# How can I get certain HTML from one page into a form onto another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a work calculator on a website I'm developing. After a person gathers the works he needs, how can I make it so when they click a button they are redirected to the contact us page and the works they've calculated are inserted into a text box?

Some more information:

In the calculator, the initial works are displayed in a table through the use of a Javascript script, like so:

```
for(var i=0; i < cartArray.length; i++){
    var cartRow = $("<tr>", {
        html:'<td class="itemname">'+cartArray[i][1]+'</td><td><input class="quantity" name="'+cartArray[i][0]+'" type="text" size="2" value="'+cartArray[i][3]+'"/></td><td><a href="#'+cartArray[i][0]+'">Remove</a></td>'
    });
    cartTable.append(cartRow);
    totalCost += (cartArray[i][2] * cartArray[i][3]);
}
```

I only need the item name, quantity and total to be inserted into the textbox. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use window.opener to refer to another page if both pages are in same domain.
For example:
document.getElementById("textfield1").value = window.opener.document.getElementById("textfield2").value;

Learn more about window.opener in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener